# Creating user invite button with Facebook API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to create a button on one of my pages that allows users to invite their friends to use my web app with them. When I click on the link I've created for the invite button, nothing happens. What am I missing? I'm new to coding so I'm a little bit lost as to what to do next.

Show.html.erb file:

```
<% if current_user %>

<div id="friends">
<p> <%= link_to "Invite Your Facebook Friends", '#', :id => 'invite_fb_friends' %></p>

<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>

<script>

$(function(){

    $("a#invite_fb_friends").click(function(){
        FB.init({
            appId:'My app ID',
            cookie:false,
            status:true
        });
        FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests', message: '<%= @user %> Invited you to collaborate on a     story.'} requestCallback;);
    };)
});
</script>
</div>
<% end %>
```

I'm using these gems for authentication

```
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
```

Here is my omniauth callback controller

```
    def facebook     
 @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)      
 if @user.persisted?       
  sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
  set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
else
  session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  redirect_to new_user_registration_url
end
end

end
```

Comment: Is your app a canvas implementation of a game? You need to be that to use invites. Other way to invite people you can read about here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#invite_to_app

Comment: Yeah it's not a canvas implementation of a game. It does have some elements of a game but it's not a canvas app. Thanks for the link. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Since posting this question I've learned that you can only enable the feature for allowing users to invite their friends to your app if it has a presence on canvas. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/canvas

Since the released v2.0 of the api the  best way to allow users to send FB invites is through the send Dialog. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog

If anyone finds a better way please let me know.

Comment: I would assume that Facebooks own FAQ on how to invite people is telling you the best way